# Compiling ROS on Windows? Ubuntu not an option

Tags: ros, nao-robot, windows, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone here actually know how to compile ROS on Windows? Please don't refer me to Ubuntu, I am using APIs that only works with Windows for my app that is controlling the Nao robot.

Ultimately, I want to be able to test C# code with the ROS Nao simulator--it doesn't appear that I can do this with NAOSim or Webots for Nao.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54136/compiling-ros-on-windows?-ubuntu-not-an-option/) by [GraceC](https://answers.ros.org/users/3269/gracec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on 2014-08-20**:
I'm curious to know what you need to test with the 'ROS Nao simulator': Gazebo support for Nao is extremely recent (a few weeks) and 100% experimental...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are [attempts to compile ROS on Windows](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros) but it is experimental. So be prepared to fix things by yourself and face more-or-less up-to-date documentation.

To be honest, achieving to compile roscpp and the other low-level layers is certainly doable if you can deal with the technical issues you will encounter by yourself but having a full environment with big software such as rviz (or other newer GUI) will be extremely challenging.

This is why I would advise you to do as less as possible on Windows. Try to compile roscpp first then write wrappers around your Windows only / proprietary softs and back to Ubuntu for your own development. This will help you not suffer too much from the lack of Windows support.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-08-07**:
Here is an alternative if you can use the WSL under Windows 10: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may or may not be helpful for your situation, but if you can get (or write) python bindings for the APIs you need, rospy runs pretty well on Windows, and that's enough to talk to a ROS graph running somewhere else. So you could run roscore on another machine or even on a VM on the Windows machine. That's the sort of thing I've done in the past when dealing with Windows-only API's.

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2